# How can I make my TF2 server public?

Tags: team-fortress-2, hosting

I've looked into this for a while and I have no idea what I'm doing. I *tried* to port forward but it only let me play on LAN, and all the guides I've looked through said to type `sv_lan 0` into the console but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Help would be much appreciated.

Oh and I'm using SteamCMD.

Comment: You should add more info like how you installed the server and where it's running.

Comment: I'm using steamCMD but I'm not sure what you mean by where it's running

Comment: I normally run TF2 servers on Ubuntu, so that involves creating rules for my router (port forwarding), allowing the traffic in the machine's firewall, and making sure the TF2 server is listening on the correct port and IP address that the port forward goes to.